# How to read only unknown types as strings in Npgsql 3.1

Tags: npgsql

Using Npgsql 3.1.5 I try to load data from a table using `NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`. Some of the columns are custom Postgres types. I want to read those as text, like Npgsql 2.2 used to do. By default Npgsql 3.1 throws an error for those:

```
System.NotSupportedException : The field 'my_custom_type_field' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 50064). You can retrieve it as a string by marking it as unknown, please see the FAQ.
```

The [FAQ](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/faq.html) suggests either setting `AllResultTypesAreUnknown` or specifying which columns are unknown, but neither of those is a good solution. `AllResultTypesAreUnknown` reads all columns as strings, which is useless to me. Specifying the individual column names one by one would take even more work than upgrading the code to use custom types properly, because there are many tables and many queries. I don't want to read *all* types as strings, I only want to read the *unknown* types as strings. In other words, read as strings when Npgsql would otherwise throw the above exception. Is there a way to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR there's no way for Npgsql to transparently read only unknown columns as text, you either have to use `AllResultTypesAreUnknown`, `UnknownResultTypeList` or change your SQL query to cast unknown columns to text.

Here's the (much too) long answer on why these are your only options.

PostgreSQL supports two encodings when reading and writing values: binary and text. Npgsql 2.2 used to use text encoding, meaning that when you read or wrote values, Npgsql would have to parse or generate a text representation for your values. Text representations are meant for human rather than programmatic consumption, and aside from being pretty inefficient this led to lots of bugs as parsing textual representation was hard to nail down 100%. Note also that Npgsql 2.2 did use binary representation in *some* cases (i.e. prepared statements), making the driver even more complicated and unpredictable.

Npgsql 3.0 did away with all that, and switched to a pure binary approach. This simplified many things and improved performance, but created a problem with regard to unknown fields: as long as Npgsql knows how to read/write the binary representation of a type all is good; but whereas textual representations of unknown types can make sense to a user, binary representations do not.

The problem is that the encoding (text or binary) of a result is determined in advance, when sending the query. If you send a query without specifying `AllResultTypesAreUnknown`/`UnknownResultTypeList`, Npgsql will get back a binary representation which it knows nothing about. At this point it's too late to do anything, except maybe to resend the query - which isn't an option. So if you want a text representation, you have to let Npgsql know that in advance.

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed explanation. Could I somehow use `MapCompositeGlobally` to map my composite types to strings as a workaround?

Comment: Nope. MapCompositeGlobally simply tells Npgsql to serialize/deserialize the *binary* representation of a given PostgreSQL composite type to the given CLR type. Again, Npgsql has no way of knowing in advance which column types are going to be returned by your query: when you send `SELECT * FROM x`, nobody knows what columns will be returned.

Comment: You'll have to properly port your application, preferably by creating actual CLR types and mapping them to the PostgreSQL composites, or use `AllResultTypesAreUnknown`/`UnknownResultTypeList` (or add casts in your query).

Comment: "creating actual CLR types and mapping them to the PostgreSQL composites". It would be useful to tell him exactly how to do this.